# `command -v` seems to only search in /usr/bin

Tags: bash, shell

For some shell script I need to store output of `command -v foo` in variables. I am checking if some binaries exist on the system. When I execute `command -v foo` in terminal, I get an output but when I execute `command -v foo` inside a shell script I don't get any output.

```
➜  tools git:(install-script) ✗ command -v node
/usr/local/bin/node


check_deps() {
    declare -A deps
    deps=( ['git']=`command -v git`
           ['gem']=`command -v gem` 
           ['node']=$(command -v node))
           # ['redis-server']=command -v redis-server
           # ['postgres']=command -v psql
           # ['sass']=command -v sass
           # ['gulp']=command -v gulp
           # ['bower']=command -v bower )
    for each in ${!deps[@]};
    do
        echo $each ${deps[$each]}
    done
}
check_deps
```

Output is:

```
node
git /usr/bin/git
gem /usr/bin/gem
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

What's happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: You are running that function in the same shell where `command -v node` worked manually? If you stick `echo "$PATH"` into that function what does it output?

Comment: you are right! when I execute the script in terminal with ./ I get output for `command -v node` but running it from sublime using the bash-build plugin I get $PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin. how do I fix this?

Comment: ah the culprit is here https://github.com/macite/sublimebashbuildsystem/blob/master/Bash.sublime-build ;)

Comment: Modify `$PATH` in the script or for that plugin or modify your `$PATH` in a file that the non-interactive, non-login (or whatever) shell that the plugin spawns also sees it.

Answer (score 1):

I was using Sublime Text which had a plugin called Bash Build system. Basically it got me a file which didn't have /usr/local/bin, this build syntax now returns proper `command -v` output:

`{
    "cmd"       : ["bash", "$file"],
    "selector"  : "source.shell",
    "osx": {
        "path"  : "$PATH:/usr/local/bin"
    }
}`